# Increase automatic System Restore points to more than just once a week?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, backup, system-restore, windows-7-backup

I've been using Windows XP for a while now, but just recently upgraded to Windows 7. I'm used to Windows XP automatically creating a new System Restore point once a day.

I notice that [Windows 7 automatically creates one only once a week](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378910%28VS.85%29.aspx). Why is that? And how can I increase the frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore`, set the `RPGlobalInterval` value, the number of seconds between restore points, to a smaller number, such as `86400` (decimal) for once every day.

For more information, see [this blog post](http://tandt-u.blogspot.com/2008/12/change-frequency-of-system-restore.html), as well as [this Microsoft Community Forums thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/is-it-possible-to-create-my-own-restore-points/b8af02ce-c7d4-47ec-a66a-80ae65453021?msgId=56d18388-4d6b-4276-bb5b-18f595184e26).

---

*Note:* If this doesn't work, try @Thraka's answer, which involves modifying the System Restore scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

### How to configure System Restore timer

The system restore timer is controlled by a scheduled task. When Automatic System Restore is enabled, the scheduled task will be updated. You can edit this scheduled task and change the trigger time to daily instead of weekly.

This scheduled task is located in the task scheduler program under the following folder:

```
Task Scheduler (Local)
    Task Scheduler Library
        Microsoft
            Windows
                SystemRestore
```

The name of the task is SR. You can also follow this tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-how-often-system-restore-creates-restore-points-in-windows-vista/

### Further Thoughts

Why do you think you need system restore more than once a week? It also automatically creates one when windows does an update. You may want a backup system instead. Personally I've rarely had to use system restore. Furthermore, since Vista, the internals of Windows is a lot more secure from corruption which would require you to do a system restore, maybe this is why they didn't default it to daily?